# map over structure with only partial match

Tags: scala, functional-programming, dictionary

I have a tree-like structure of abstract classes and case classes representing an Abstract Syntax Tree of a small language.

For the top abstract class i've implemented a method `map`:

```
abstract class AST {
...
  def map(f: (AST => AST)): AST = {
     val b1 =  this match {
      case s: STRUCTURAL => s.smap(f) // structural node for example IF(expr,truebranch,falsebranch)
      case _ => this // leaf, // leaf, like ASSIGN(x,2)
    }
    f(b1)
  }
...
```

The smap is defined like:

```
 override def smap(f: AST => AST) = {
    this.copy(trueb = trueb.map(f), falseb = falseb.map(f))
  }
```

Now im writing different "transformations" to insert, remove and change nodes in the AST.

For example, remove adjacent NOP nodes from blocks:

```
def handle_list(l:List[AST]) = l match {
  case (NOP::NOP::tl) => handle_list(tl)
  case h::tl => h::handle_list(tl)
  case Nil => Nil
}

ast.map {
  case BLOCK(listofstatements) => handle_list(listofstatements)
}
```

If I write like this, I end up with `MatchError` and I can "fix it" by changing the above map to:

```
ast.map {
  case BLOCK(listofstatements) => handle_list(listofstatements)
  case a => a
}
```

Should I just live with all those `case a => a` or could I improve my `map` method(or other parts) in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the argument to `map` a `PartialFunction`:

```
def map(f: PartialFunction[AST, AST]): AST = {
  val idAST: PartialFunction[AST, AST] = {case a => a}
  val g = f.orElse(idAST)

  val b1 =  this match {
    case s: STRUCTURAL => s.smap(g)
    case _ => this
  }
  g(b1)
}
```

Comment: wow! I keep on seeing marvelous things in Scala. That was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: That code was probably slightly wrong, because I didn't notice `f` was used as the argument of `smap`. Fixed.

Comment: isnt it `orElse` instead of `andThen`?

Comment: Of course it is (and it takes a `PartialFunction` and not just a `Function` to boot, so I need a bit more type annotation to make it work).

Answer (score 4):

If tree transformations are more than a minor aspect of your project, I highly recommend you use [Kiama](http://code.google.com/p/kiama/)'s Rewriter module to implement them. It implements Stratego-like strategy-driven transformations. It has a very rich set of strategies and strategy combinators that permit a complete separation of traversal logic (which for the vast majority of cases can be taken "off the shelf" from the supplied strategies and combinators) from (local) transformations (which are specific to your AST and you supply, of course).

Comment: Very interesting. Will look into it!